# Product of very large numbers

Tags: java

How to multiply two 100 digits number which are inputted as strings. 
Note: we are not allowed to use BigInteger or BigDecimal classes of java.

Comment: Hint: Bits or Strings

Comment: Frankly? [The Art of Computer Programming](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/taocp.html), volume 2, section 4.3

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is that you multiply them the way you learned in high school. So you take the lowest digit of the second number and iterate all the way up over the first, then do the second digit and add up the results until you got the total. Basically you simply automate what you normally do by hand.

To give you an example on how to do this I can show you the following code as I find these kind of questions exceedingly hard for beginning programmers. It should show good program composition and a lot of the techniques required to complete the task.

It is of course missing a vital piece of implementation though :).

```
public class DecimalNumber {

    public static String multiply(String x, String y) {
        String intermediateResult = "0";
        for (int i = 0; i < y.length(); i++) {
            char ydc = y.charAt(y.length() - i - 1);
            int yd = toDigitValue(ydc);
            String result = multiply(yd, x);
            String shiftedResult = shift(i, result);
            intermediateResult = add(intermediateResult, shiftedResult);
        }
        return intermediateResult;
    }

    private static String add(String x, String y) {
        int digitsToAdd = Math.max(x.length(), y.length());
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(1 + digitsToAdd);

        int carry = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < digitsToAdd; i++) {
            int xd;
            if (i >= x.length()) {
                xd = 0;
            } else {
                char xdc = x.charAt(x.length() - i - 1);
                xd = toDigitValue(xdc);
            }

            int yd;
            if (i >= y.length()) {
                yd = 0;
            } else {
                char ydc = y.charAt(y.length() - i - 1);
                yd = toDigitValue(ydc);
            }

            int digitAdd = xd + yd + carry;
            if (digitAdd >= 10) {
                carry = digitAdd / 10;
                digitAdd = digitAdd % 10;
            } else {
                carry = 0;
            }
            char digitMulChar = toDigitCharacter(digitAdd);
            result.insert(0, digitMulChar);
        }
        if (carry != 0) {
            result.insert(0, carry);
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    private static String shift(int shift, String valueToShift) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(valueToShift.length() + shift);
        result.append(valueToShift);
        for (int i = 0; i < shift; i++) {
            result.append('0');
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    private static String multiply(int yd, String x) {
        // TODO implement
        throw new IllegalStateException("Method not implemented");
    }

    private static int toDigitValue(char digitAsCharacter) {
        return Integer.parseInt("" + digitAsCharacter);
    }

    private static char toDigitCharacter(int digitValue) {
        return Character.forDigit(digitValue, 10);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(multiply("999", "999"));
    }
}
```

---

I actually found this kind of code in software once. Don't do that, just use a big integer library that operates on bytes. Or rather 64 bit `long` values if you want any kind of performance.

---

Note that if you have already had lessons on how to perform fast binary operations you probably need to replicate that than the answer above.

Comment: Note that it is kind of the idea of this question to understand how to convert a problem you have already solved in real life into a solution that works for a computer. So next time you get one of these questions try and apply logic to the knowledge you already possess.

Comment: Could do Russian peasant multiplication too.